# C++ Segmentation fault using cstrings

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am trying to pass c-strings into a function and have a table 6x6 printed out. However my code keeps compiling with an error. A segmentation fault. I understand that a seg fault is when the program looks for something that isn't there. I'm not sure how to fix this or how to alter this even after much research. Any suggestions would very much be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fillarrays(int labs[][6]);
void printarrays(int labs[][6]);

int main()
{

    int labs[6][6];

    fillarrays(labs);
    printarrays(labs);

    return 0;
}

void fillarrays(int labs[][6])
{

    for(int row = 0; row<=6; row ++)
    {
        for(int col=0; col<=6; col++)
        {
            labs[row][col] = row;
        }
    }
}
void printarrays(int labs[][6])
{

    cout << "Labs: " << '\t' << '\t' << endl;;
    for(int rows=0 ; rows<6; rows++)
    {
        for(int cols=0; cols<6; cols++)
        {
            cout << '\t' << labs[rows][cols] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm new to all this so please be patient. I'm a 35 year old CIS student taking C++ for the first time. I've been working on this assignment for 2 weeks now. I am trying to pass c-strings into a function and have a table 6x6 printed out. However my code keeps compiling with an error. A segmentation fault. I understand that a seg fault is when the program looks for something that isn't there. I'm not sure how to fix this or how to alter this even after much research. Any suggestions would very much be appreciated.

Comment: `for(int row = 0; row<=6;row ++)` loops 7 times

Comment: In fillarrays()  the 2 for are wrong it's <6 not <=6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

labs[6][6] is an array with 6 rows first one is [0] and last one is [5], the same for cols, so change `<=6` to `<6` in `fillarrays`.

```
for(int row = 0; row<6;row ++) {
    for(int col=0; col<6; col++) {
        labs[row][col] = row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int row = 0; row<=6;row ++) {
    for(int col=0; col<=6; col++) {
        labs[row][col] = row;
    }
}
```

Look closely here - this fills a 7x7 array (indices 0 to 6 for rows and columns). But the array is only 6x6, so you're trying to write outside teh bounds of the array.

This is a reasonably common mistake; change the `<=`s to `<`s.